# in_array function is not working

Tags: php, arrays

This code should return `TRUE` value:

```
<?php
      $return = in_array(array(1, 2), array(1, 2));
?>
```

but `in_array` returns FALSE.

Comment: But there's not an array containing and array with the values 1 and 2 in the other?

Comment: considering you are pretty new take a look at the answers and pick whenever you consider is the best.

Comment: I have two arrays, first (1, 2, 3, 4, 5) and second (1, 4), I want to check if elements from second array are in first. How to do that in easy way?

Answer (score 13):

`in_array` checks if a value exists in an array.

Your `$needle` doens't exists at all as a value of `$haystack`

that would be ok if your `$haystack` was

```
array(1,2,3,array(1,2))
```

Notice in this case `array(1,2)` actually is found inside as expected

If you want to check whenever 2 arrays are equal i suggest you the `===` operator

```
($a === $b) // TRUE if $a and $b have the same key/value pairs in the same order and of the same types.
```

Answer (score 5):

Based on your example, you may want to look into [array_intersect()](http://php.net/array_intersect). It compares arrays in a fashion that may better align with your spec.

Answer (score 4):

According to the PHP Manual for [`in_array`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.in-array.php), the function's syntax is:

```
bool in_array ( mixed $needle , array $haystack [, bool $strict = FALSE ] )
```

So you need to supply a `$needle` value as the first argument. This explains why your example returns FALSE. However, these examples will each return TRUE:

```
in_array(1, array(1, 2));
in_array(2, array(1, 2));
in_array(array(1, 2), array(1, 2, array(1, 2)))
```

That said, it might help if you explain exactly what you are trying to do. Perhaps `in_array` is not the function you need.

Answer (score 4):

Your first array isn't contained in the second array, it's equal.

This returns true:

```
var_dump(in_array(array(1, 2), array(1, 2, array(1, 2))));
```

Answer (score 3):

Are you interested in [intersection](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-intersect.php)?

```
$arr1 = array(1, 2);
$arr2 = array(1, 2);

$return = array_intersect($arr1, $arr2);

if(count($return) === count($arr1)) {
    // all are present in arr2
}
```

Answer (score 2):

First parameter is the value you're looking for in the second parameter (array)
http://php.net/manual/fr/function.in-array.php

Answer (score 2):

you missunderstand in_array see offiziell docs: http://uk.php.net/in_array

```
<?php
$a = array(array('p', 'h'), array('p', 'r'), 'o');

if (in_array(array('p', 'h'), $a)) {
    echo "'ph' was found\n";
}

if (in_array(array('f', 'i'), $a)) {
    echo "'fi' was found\n";
}

if (in_array('o', $a)) {
    echo "'o' was found\n";
}
?>
```

Answer (score 2):

array(1,2) is not in array(1,2) it is array(1,2),

`$return = in_array(array(1, 2), array(array(1, 2)));`

would return true. (more an extension of yes123's answer)

Answer (score 1):

In your case, the first parameter of in_array should not be an array, but an integer. What you are doing with that code is checking for the presence of an array inside the array, which is not there. A correct form would be:

```
in_array(1, array(1, 2)); // true
```

Comment: this is not true. You can check for nested array with in_array. I explained it in my answer

Comment: It is true for the case presented here, in which the user is searching for an integer inside an array.

Answer (score 1):

if second array looks like this

```
array(array(1, 2));
```

then return true